# How to work properly with strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I know there is a rule about strings in C# that says:

> When we create a textual string of type string, we can never change its value! When putting different value for a string variable thje first string will stay in memory and variable (which is kind of reference type) just gets the address of the new string.

So doing something like this:

```
string a = "aaa";
a = a.Trim(); // Creates a new string
```

is not recommended.
But what if I need to do some actions on the string according to user preferences, like so:

```
string a = "aaa";
if (doTrim)
   a = a.Trim();
if (doSubstring)
   a = a.Substring(...);

etc...
```

How can I do it without creating new strings on every action ?
I thougt about sending the string to a function by ref, like so:

```
void DoTrim(ref string value)
{
  value = value.Trim(); // also creates new string
}
```

But this also creates a new string...
Can someone please tell me if there is a way of doing it without wasteing memory on each action ?

Comment: You can't change a string without creating a new instance, strings are immutable.

Comment: You could use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: *So doing something like this is not recommended.* - it is entirely recommended. In fact, it's the only way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: "doing something like this: ... is not recommended". Sure it is. It's just that for cases where you're modifying a string value (hundreds of) thousands of times there may be more efficient ways (notably `StringBuilder` and for some cases character arrays).

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the question to suggest that strings are being appended to iteratively. There's no need for a StringBuilder here.

Comment: Creating new strings is just how .NET works. It's really only a performance problem if you have lots and lots of strings being generated (like in a loop). Don't get paralyzed trying to optimize things that aren't a problem.

Comment: You could create a function that reconstructs your string given the many different procedures you would support.  You could probably do this best using a StringBuilder as others have mentioned.  At the end of the day, though, you should ask yourself if the amount of work doing that is worth saving the additional overhead of strings.  I do understand where you are coming from, though.  A friend and I wrote an XNA game that posted debug strings on the screen every frame.  The GC went nuts. Generally, though, you don't often deal with that kind of situation to warrant such low-level manipulation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct in that the operations you're performing are creating new strings, and not mutating a single string.

You are incorrect in that this is generally problematic or something to be avoided.

If your strings are hundreds of thousands of characters, then sure, copying all of those just to remove a few leading spaces, or to add a few characters to the end of it (repeatedly, in a loop, in particular) can actually be a problem.

If your strings aren't large, and you're not performing *many* (an in thousands of) operations on the string, then you almost certainly don't have a problem.

Now there are a handful of contexts, generally rather rare, that *do* run into problems with string manipulation.  Probably the most common of the problematic contexts is appending a bunch of strings together, as doing so means copying all of the previously appended data for each new addition.  If you're in that situation consider using something like a `StringBuilder` or a single call to `string.Concat` (the overload accepting a sequence of strings to concat) to perform this operation.

Other contexts are, for example, programs dealing with processing DNA strands.  They'll often be taking strings of millions of characters and creating hundreds of thousands of many thousand character long substrings of that string.  Using standard C# string operations would therefore result in a *lot* of unnecessary copying.  People writing such programs end up creating objects that can represent a substring of another string *without copying the data* and instead referring to the existing string's underlying data source with an offset.

Comment: `Stringbuilder` also has a nice advantage of producing "more readable" (at a glance) code.

Comment: @Gusdor That's subjective and also highly dependent on the situation.  Personally I almost never use `StringBuilder`.  I use `Concat` whenever I want to concatenate a lot of strings together.  Manipulating immutable objects is also generally easier to reason about; mutable objects are generally easier to do mean and convoluted things with.

Comment: @Gusdor - That's debatable. Personally I find well-formatted string concatenations much clearer than a bunch of `StringBuilder` calls.

Comment: @Servy `"I'm ".Concat("sure ").Concat("colleagues ").Concat("love ").Concat("that.");`

Comment: @Gusdor - Servy even mentions in the above about [the override that accepts a sequence of strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w(v=vs.110).aspx)..

Comment: @Gusdor Since all of those strings are known at compile time, I'd write them as one compile time literal.  If they're a bunch of statically defined string variables, I'd use the `+` operator.  If it's an unknown number of strings (the one situation in which `StringBuilder` was designed to solve) I'd use a *single* call to `string.Concat` passing in a sequence of values to concat.

Comment: @Sayse up to 4 strings, or we have to build an array or `IEnumerable`. TLDR, religious war.

Comment: @Gusdor Which in most situations that you would want to use a `StringBuilder` you *already have*.  Most uses of a `StringBuilder` end up `foreach`-ing something and appending to the SB in the loop.  You can replace such a loop with a all to `string.Concat`.  Shorter, simpler, semantically represents the operation being performed, and of comparable performance.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking my neck out here a bit so I'll preface with saying in most cases Servy's answer is the correct answer.  However, if you really do need lower level access and less string allocations, you could consider creating a character buffer (simple array for instance) that is big enough to fit your processed string and allow you direct manipulation of the characters.  There are some significant downfalls to this, though.  Including that you'll probably have to write your own Substring() and Trim() modifiers, and your buffer will likely be bigger than your input strings in many cases to accommodate unexpected string sizes.  Once you are done manipulating your buffer, you could then package the character array up as a String.  Since all of your manipulations are done on a single buffer, you should save a lot of allocations.

I would seriously consider if the above is worth the hassle, but if you really need the performance, this is the best solution I can think of.

Comment: Unlikely to be the case, but it's always a good idea to be aware of those corner cases where something like this does make sense for real (not theoretical) performance reasons.

Comment: @Bobson Yep, and that's exactly what I'm addressing.  Sometimes you do need the performance, but I think it's a rarity.  If OP really needs the performance, this solution might help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel uncomfortable creating new strings? There is a reason for the string API to be designed this way. For example, immutable objects are thread-safe (and they allow for a more functional programming style).

If you replace your simple string code by stringbuilders, your code might be more error-prone in multithreading scenarios (which is quite normal in a web application for example).

StringBuilders are used for concatenating strings, inserting characters, removing characters, etc. But they will need to reallocate and copy their internal characters arrays every now and then, too.

When you speak about memory consumption you have started to [micro-optimize your code. Don't.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

BTW: Have a look at the LINQ API. What does each operation do? Rats - it creates a new enumerator! A query like `foos.Where(bar).Select(baz).FirstOrDefault()` could certainly be memory-optimized by just creating a single enumerator object and modifying the criteria it applies when enumerating. </irony>

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it without creating new strings on every action?

You should only worry about that if you're handling big strings or if you're doing many string operations in a short period of time.

Even then, the performance loss due to creating more references is minimal.
The Garbage Collector has to collect all the unused string variables, but hey - that only really matters if you're doing MANY string operations.

So rather **focus on readability** in your code, **rather than** trying to **optimize** its **performance** in the first place.

---

If you really have to keep the same reference of string, you can simply use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on what your exact use case is, but you might want to explore using the [StringBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) which you can use to build and modify strings.

Comment: I'd like to downvote the downvoters.  If you're dealing with large strings, manipulating them with a `StringBuilder` is the right answer.  A `StringBuilder` can do more than append.  It can change individual characters, length, or replace substrings.  It's not always the right answer.  Use it in a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @DavidCrowell But it doesn't apply to the operations the OP is performing here.  (In a way that's any more efficient than native strings.)  It is not generally going to be any more performant at trimming characters from the start of the string, nor from creating a substring of another string without copying that data.  While it's *possible* to do all of these things with a `StringBuilder`, it's not *optimized* to do them and as such it's not actually likely to be superior to just using native string operations.

Comment: I think the compiler even optimises `StringBuilder` to string concatenation when it thinks it'll be more optimal.

Comment: @Stijn No, it will never do such a thing.  What it *will* do is take a static number of string concatenations, i.e. `a+b+c+d` and transform it into a *single* call to `string.Concat` rather than 3 different calls.  So it results in `string.Concat(a,b,c,d)` rather than `string.Concat(a,String.Concat(b,string.Concat(c,d)))`.  This of course means that 0 intermediate strings are created, rather than 2.

Comment: @Servy I probably misremember reading such a thing, perhaps it was the other way around.

Comment: @Stijn It will never do the reverse either.  Also see the edit to my last comment.

Comment: As the OP said "if I need to do some actions on the string according to user preferences", which is why I said "it will depend on what your exact use case is".